# Why no strikethrough markdown?

Tags: feature-request, markdown

I understand that strikethrough can be achieved with the standard HTML `<strike>` or `<del>`, but why does Stack Exchange not support the standard Markdown ~~strikethrough~~ syntax? After all, you can get *italic* text with HTML `<i>` or with Markdown `_` or `*`, so redundancy doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: Markdown is maddeningly standard, even within the same site, especially when its not.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I am not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: Because it wasn't a part of the Markdown specification. I believe it was added to CommonMark (?) which will be implemented on our sites at some point in the future.

Comment: Hm. The markdown references I found all mentioned it. Perhaps I am mistaken!

Comment: @Felthry This is the Markdown spec: https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax - It makes no reference to strikethrough whatsoever. Some other sites added it in because they wanted to.

Comment: I was being funny about how chat and the actual site did things differently @Felthry.

Comment: @animuson Ah, okay. Thanks; I had found [these](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet) [references](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/210298617-Markdown-Text-101-Chat-Formatting-Bold-Italic-Underline-), both of which include the same strikethrough syntax. I had assumed the former was the official spec.

Comment: Strikethrough jokes are so bloody annoying.  Anything done that prevents them is good.  Including banning the use of <strike>idiotic workarounds used by unfunny jackasses</strike> fake strike through humor.

Comment: My intended use case was to strike out answers that turn out to be irrelevant to the specific case asked about, but might be of use in other cases. For example, if someone added clarifying information to their question that rendered an answer incorrect.

Comment: imho strikethrough can be used very effectively to illustrate something just like bold/italic. There is overuse of course, but we also don't ban capitals and boy are those overused sometimes!